# Microsoft Visual Studio C# Express 4.0 download help files

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I go to "Help" click on "view help" and am directed [here](http://127.0.0.1:47873/help/1-5404/ms.help?method=f1&query=msdnstart&product=VS&productVersion=100&locale=en-US).  How do I install local help?

Comment: You posted a localhost address...

Comment: That is the link I got when I clicked help.
The topic you requested could not be found in local help.
Have you installed the local help content?
How to install and configure local help using Help Library Manager.
Check online for your topic at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(MSDNSTART)&rd=true
Other options to try
Do you have the right content installed locally?
How to add new content to your local help store with Help Library Manager.
© 2010 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved
Send Feedback on this topic to Microsoft.

Comment: Did you follow what it said to do?

Comment: "Launch Help Library Manager from the "Help" menu in your software application. Click "Help" > "Manage Help settings".

Click "Check for updates". The next screen shows content you have installed locally.

HLM will check for updates and display the update status for your local help content. This might take a few moments.

The status area at the bottom of the screen shows the total size of the updates. Click the "Update" button at the bottom of the screen to download and install the updates.

HLM will install the content and periodically report on its progress."

__I don't have the HLM file__

Comment: HLM is the Help Library Manager...

Comment: OK... I have __no__ locally installed help files.  Yes I have the Help Library Manager, but no help files.

Where can I download them?

Comment: @soandos let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1017/discussion-between-wizlog-and-soandos)

Comment: actually I can't sign in to chat

Comment: No help related updates.  Just security updates

Comment: Click on the link...

Comment: Click the move this discussion to chat please.

Comment: Sorry, your right, just never clicked OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the help files from the web.  Go under the help menu and *Manage Help Settings*.  You can download them from there.

I prefer to just prefer to dock MSDN as a webpage on one side.  A trick you can do is eliminate the sidebar.  Just click the divider on the MSDN page and it toggles between three or four different states.  Toggle it til the sidebar is off.

Comment: After clicking *Manage Help Settings* I'm asked to browse for a local file.

Comment: Odd, you used the web installer or the ISO download?  And which browser?